# Why continue doesn't work while raising errors

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why continue doesn't work when I'm rising errors:

```
while True:
        a = int(raw_input('Type integer with 9 numbers '))
        if len(str(a)) < 9 or len(str(a)) >9:
                raise NameError('Wrong Number. Try again...')
                continue
        if not istance(a, int):
                raise ValueError("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
                continue
        else:
                print a
                break
```

Could you point out my mistake(s)?

Comment: `raise` throws an exception. Normal execution is suspended and python finds the innermost exception handler (a `try / except` statement pair). If python doesn't find a handler the program terminates.

Answer (score 3):

Try `print 'Wrong Number. Try again...'` instead of `raise`.

`raise` will trigger an exception, which basically means your program is interrupted when the instruction is reached, the the exception is propagated up the call stack until it is caught by a `try...except` statement.

What you seem to achieve here is to *display* an error message to the user because the input is incorrect. Simply use the `print` statement for that purpose.

Comment: I've tested try.. 'except:   except ValueError:
                print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
                continue ' Is it possible to use except for a condition: 'if len(str(a)) < 9 or len(str(a)) >9' ?

Comment: Take out the "if" and place that line inside "try". Then you can catch the exception like this.

Answer (score 1):

`raise` will trigger an exception and the program will terminate.

I find a few contradictions in your code:

> You are converting the user input to an int class, so `if isinstance(a, int)` is not at all required because `a` will point to an int class already. If in case, user input could not be converted to "int" then `ValueError` exception will be raised and program execution would end right there, so not event the first `if ...` statement will be evaluated.

I would rewrite the code with little changes:

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(raw_input('Type integer with 9 numbers '))
    except ValueError:
        print "Non-numeric chars were entered"
        continue
    if len(str(a)) != 9:
        print "Wrong number"
        continue
    else:
        #do whatever you wanna do
        print 'You entered nine digits...hurray'
        break
```